# actual tree structure of iframe document

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I could be wrong ,but about iframe all i know is this - inside the iframe it creates it's own document object.But i have few others confusion. [w3school's example says :](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentdocument.asp)

```
var x = document.getElementById("myframe");
var y = (x.contentWindow || x.contentDocument);
if (y.document)y = y.document;
y.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

> in the explanation it says ,contentDocument retruns the document
>   object  generated by iframe element.

If so, then why we need to gain access with y.document.What i am trying to say is ,if x.contentDocument returns the document object then why we need `x.contentDocument.document` to have the full object. Can anyone explain the  actual ***tree structure*** of this ?

if it is a document object ,the why i am having error while trying to extract the innerHTML of a div element placed inside the iframe ?

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe style='bordre:1px solid black;width:100px;height:100px;' id='myframe'><div id='mydiv'>lol</div>></iframe>
<script>
    var x = document.getElementById("myframe");
var y = (x.contentWindow || x.contentDocument);
if (y.document)y = y.document;
console.log(y.document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The first thing to do is to consult sources other than w3school.  While they seem to have somehow mastered Google search relevance to get themselves near the top of search results, very few people think that's because they are actually one of the better sources of educational content.  I'm personally using a Chrome add-on that lets me block sites from my own search results and I use it to block w3school because I always favor some other site in the search results.

Comment: @kaiido it is returning null....

Comment: Oh and excuse me, I misread your snippet. Actually, your way of doing it is not valid. The innerHTML of your iframe will be ignored by all user-agents supporting the iframe element . You have to set it an src so that it returns a documentElement from a remote file.

Comment: still don't get it.,can you use simpler words :-|

Comment: when you are doing `<iframe>some content</iframe>`, the `some content` part will be ignored by all browsers which do support iframeElement. It can just be used as a fallback for those that don't know this element. The iframe element is used to render a remote document. You use it by setting its `src` property to the url of said document : i.e `<iframe src="yourOtherDoc.html"></iframe>` Please read [the following](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

Comment: ok i understand that, but show it or not, the div element is there.Then why can't i access it with javascript ?

Comment: No the div is not there when the browser do render the html. It's being ignored and thus disappears into nothingness. `nihil fit ex nihilo`

Comment: @jfriend00—they certainly seem to have put a lot of effort into search engine optimisation. Pity they don't put the same effort into their tutorials.

Comment: @AL-zami, to convince yourself, you can try to replace your div with a `<script>alert("hey I'm here")</script>` and see that it's actually not there.

Comment: @kaiido i got it. thanks a lot .. :))

Answer (score 1):

You need to have 2 separate html files. We will call them `parent.html` and `child.html`. For this example, these 2 files will be located in the same domain and sub-domain.

#### Locations

Although this simple tree structure has both files as siblings, when we use iframes, the file with the iframe is referred to as the parent and the file inside the iframe is referred to as the child.

#### parent.html

```
    <!Doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Parent</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <!--| border is spelled wrong, missing `src` attribute, there's an extra `>` at the end of the non-existent div |--> 
    <!--<iframe style='bordre:1px solid black;width:100px;height:100px;' id='myframe'><div id='mydiv'>lol</div>></iframe>--> 

    <!--| This is the proper way to create an iframe |-->
        <iframe id="myframe" name="myframe" scrolling="no" src="http://arcx.s3.amazonaws.com/demo1/child.html" style="border:1px solid black;width:100px;height:100px;">Anything inbetween the iframe tags will appear if the browser cannot render the iframe properly, so if the iframe is done correctly, anything here will never get rendered</iframe>
        <script>
/* When the iframe is loaded, get Child's #mydiv HTML content and log it to the console */
            var iFrame = document.getElementById("myframe"); // Reference to iframe
            iFrame.onload = function() {
                var childWin = iFrame.contentWindow, // Reference to child.html window 
                        target = childWin.document.getElementById('mydiv'), // Reference to child's div
                     /* target =  childWin.document.querySelector('div'), */// Alternate reference to child's div
                        content = target.innerHTML; // Get div's content
                console.log(content);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

#### child.html

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Child</title>
    <style>
        #mydiv { outline: 2px dashed red; background: black; width: 84px; height: 84px; font: 900 32px/1.5 Consolas; text-align: center; color: red; margin: 2px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mydiv">LOL</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a [Tutorial](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/)

Comment: so,as my browser can recognize iframe,i can see the child.html page not the content inside the iframe tag ?

Comment: Yep, an iframe is a "window" to another document. In this example, the document in the iframe (child.html) is on the same domain as the main page that has the iframe (parent.html). In this situation, we are able to communicate from the parent to the child and vice versa. If the child page was elsewhere (ie different domain, even different sub-domain) the browser would block any communication between parent and child because of the risk of XSS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting . There are of course ways to workaround such security measures.

Comment: What about the global variables across the parent and child? Can we access them either way in case the parent and child are from the same domain?